# PHP HTML Tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display

```
$row["name"]
```

through the form of a HTML Table, like this:

```
echo "<html>
<table class="."table".">
  <tr>
    <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>";
```

I'm getting the row variable from here, too:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE public = 1";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("Server name: %s", $row["name"].'<br>');
    printf ("Hostname: %s", $row["host"].'<br>');
    printf ("Port: %s", $row["port"].'<br>');
    printf ("Player count: %s", $row["players"].'<br>');
    printf ("Server Status: %s", $row["status"].'<br>');
    printf ("Last pinged: %s", $row["last_ping"].'<br>');
    printf ("Current ms: %s", $row["ms"].'<br>');

}

$result->free();
}
```

It does successfully display the information printed, but doesn't seem to be able to put it into a table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R78cg.png

Comment: The second code isn't being put into a table it looks like.

Comment: @HarryDenley if you look at the imgur link, it's still creating the table, just not displaying the $row["name"]. I've tried multiple ways of it, it's having none of it.

Comment: `<table class="."table".">` ? – Try `<table class=\"table\">` or `<table class='table'>` More than likely the issue.

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($row) before you output the HTML, to check the contents of the $row variable?

Comment: Also, what exactly is your HTML output in the browser with view source?

Comment: Plus, you need to have your `<table>` outside your loop, then the rows you wish to display `inside` your loop.

Comment: Yeah, the table row there would be <table class=table>. That's not valid html since attributes must be quoted

Comment: Stylistic suggestion: Double quotes are for interpolating variables, but you are still using concatenation. The whole thing should be "<html>
<table class='table'><tr><td>{$row['name']}</td></tr></table></html>". Or even better, don't echo it and go into php mod just o print the var. ?> <html><table class="table"><tr><td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td></tr></table></html>

Comment: Any reason why you use printf instead of echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually assign any of the row values in the WHILE loop to a variable.  If the SQL statement returns more than 1 row, you need to build an array in your WHILE loop to use for later.

Define your array first

```
$myarray = array();
```

Then assign the object returned from the SQL statement to the array

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $myarray[] = $row;
    //your other printf statements if you want to keep them
}
```

Now you have a populated $myarray where the first level key is the row number.  Since you are probably building a dynamic table (one whose size depends on the amount of information returned), you'll also need to incorporate PHP into the process.

```
<table class = "table">
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($myarray); $i++){
             echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>";
                      echo $myarray[$i]["name"];
                 echo "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
        } 
    ?>
</table>
```

In the above, you run a for loop on every item in $myarray and for each row returned from your original database pull, a new table row and corresponding table column are created.

Comment: Managed to get it working, really need to refresh my PHP, not done it for so long. :L Thanks for the help, greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: `~ Another Happy Ending ~`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried taking the whole table out of the php echo statement?

So having it as html then just echoing the row inside the table

```
<td><?php echo $row["name"] ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
echo "<html>
<table class="."table".">
  <tr>
    <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>";
```

will echo this:

```
<html>
<table class=table>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

thats not valid html

as suggested by Kyle Goslan you should try it like this:

```
<html>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

this is how i would do it:

```
<html>
<table class="table">
   <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
   </tr>
   <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM servers WHERE public = 1";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
           </td>
       </tr>
   <?php }
}

$result->free();
?>
```

Comment: I was just about to make a comment about that. I wasn't going to put in an actual answer, because questions like these tend to open up both a Pandora's box and the proverbial "can of worms".

Comment: Yeah, i've previously tried that, but it's done nothing. The table is displaying, but blank. It's not getting the variable, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the table row `<tr></tr>` inside the while loop and use separate `<td>` columns for each data field.

Sample code:

```
echo '<table>';
while{$row}
{
 echo '<tr>
       <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
       </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```